# Simple method of calculating bytes/kb/mb/tb/gb

Tags: php

I have wanted to create a script like this for ages. I've attempted it below, for some reason nothing is display. Does someone else have any examples of a class such as this. What do you think is an efficient way to display this. This is based on the user entering a value.

```
<?php


    if($_GET['step'] == 2) {

    $bytes = $_GET['bytes'];

    echo $bytes; 

    $kilobyte = 1024;
$megabyte = $kilobyte * 1024;
$gigabyte = $megabyte * 1024;
$terabyte = $gigabyte * 1024;

if (($bytes >= 0) && ($bytes < $kilobyte)) {
    return $bytes;

}
   if (($bytes >= $kilobyte) && ($bytes < $megabyte))
    {
    return $kb = round($bytes / $kilobyte); 

}
     if (($bytes >= $megabyte) && ($bytes < $gigabyte))
     {
    return $mb = round($bytes / $megabyte);
}
    if (($bytes >= $gigabyte) && ($bytes < $terabyte))
    {
    return $gb = round($bytes / $gigabyte);

}
    if ($bytes >= $terabyte)
    {
    return $tb = round($bytes / $terabyte);
}
    else {
    return $bytes;
}

    $content .= "<h2>Details of Memory Size </h2>

    <table>

        <tr>
                            <th>Bytes</th>
            <th>KB</th>                 
            <th>MB</th>
            <th>GB</th>
                            <th>TB</th

        </tr>";





            $content .= "<tr >
                    <td> $bytes</td>
                                            <td>$kb </td>
                                            <td>$mb</td>
                                            <td>$gb</td>
                                            <td>$tb</td>

                                        </tr>       
                                   ";




    }

   else {


   $content = " <form action='index.php?step=2' method='post'>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <th>Enter the number of kilobytes on unix drive</th> 
   <td><input type='text' name='bytes'/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <input type='submit' />
   </td>
   </table>
   </form>";

    echo $bytes; 
   }


 ?>
```

Comment: why are you using return there? Is there something you're not showing us?

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to do something like this?

```
<html>

   <head>
     <title>Byte scale calculator</title>
   </head>

   <body>
<?php

  if ($_GET['step'] == 2) {

    // Handle submissions

    $bytes = $_GET['bytes'];

    // Calculate KB
    $kilobyte = 1024;
    $kb = round($bytes / $kilobyte, 2);

    // Calculate MB
    $megabyte = $kilobyte * 1024;
    $mb = round($bytes / $megabyte, 2);

    // Calculate GB
    $gigabyte = $megabyte * 1024;
    $gb = round($bytes / $gigabyte, 2);

    // Calculate TB
    $terabyte = $gigabyte * 1024;
    $tb = round($bytes / $terabyte, 2);

?>
     <h2>Details of Memory Size </h2>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Bytes</th>
         <th>KB</th>                 
         <th>MB</th>
         <th>GB</th>
         <th>TB</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $bytes; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $kb; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $mb; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $gb; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $tb; ?></td>
       </tr>
     </table>    
 <?php } ?>

     <form action='' method='get'>
       <input type='hidden' name='step' value='2' />
       <!-- You had the form method set to post, but you were trying to fecth data from $_GET -->
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>Enter the number of kilobytes on unix drive</th> 
           <td><input type='text' name='bytes' /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type='submit' /></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
   </body>        

 </html>
```

There are way too many changes to note them all, so if there's anything you don't understand feel free to ask with a comment at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

A function I found a while ago in the php docs comments for converting bytes to human readable supporting SI and Binary prefixes:

```
function size_readable($size, $max = null, $system = 'bi', $retstring = '%01.2f %s')
{
    // Pick units
    $systems['si']['prefix'] = array('B', 'K', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB');
    $systems['si']['size']   = 1000;
    $systems['bi']['prefix'] = array('B', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB');
    $systems['bi']['size']   = 1024;
    $sys = isset($systems[$system]) ? $systems[$system] : $systems['si'];

    // Max unit to display
    $depth = count($sys['prefix']) - 1;
    if ($max && false !== $d = array_search($max, $sys['prefix'])) {
        $depth = $d;
    }

    // Loop
    $i = 0;
    while ($size >= $sys['size'] && $i < $depth) {
        $size /= $sys['size'];
        $i++;
    }

    return sprintf($retstring, $size, $sys['prefix'][$i]);
}
```